# Django: How to set the size for the image? (models.ImageField)

Tags: django, django-models

I use Django 1.5.

How to set the size for the image? For example, the user must add images more than 200 * 200.

**models.py:**

```
class UserNew(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the forms' clean method.

```
class UserNewForm(forms.ModelForm):
     def clean_photo(self):
         photo = self.cleaned_data.get('photo',None)
         if not photo:
             raise ValidationError("Something went wrong")
         if photo._height < 200 or photo._width < 200:
             raise ValidationError("Photo dimensions are too small (minimum 200X200 )")

         return photo
```